# How can I set a local variable using a string?

Tags: javascript, scope

I need to set a local variable inside a for loop in a function, but part of the name of this var needs to be a string, more specifically an array index.

See the example:

```
function MyFunction () {
    var strings = ["first","second","third","fourth"];

    for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        var "My_" + strings[i] + "_var" = "Hi, I'm the " + strings[i] + " var!";
    }
}
```

I know this is not the correct way, I'm just illustrating what I want to do. I've already tried using `window[]` or `this[]`, but seems like the var becomes global.

Comment: Why do you want to create a variable this way?

Comment: Because I want to show different messages on different elements of my website, and I'm trying to minify my code using a for loop and arrays.

Comment: This is a very bad pattern just to minify code. For code minification look at "JSmin" or "yui compressor".

Comment: You really don't want to do this; I suggest posting more code and explanation of the problem you are trying to solve in a new question, for better solutions.

Comment: The duplicate question even though it has a bad title answers this perfect!

Answer (score 0):

A way is using objects you can make the object's variable name a string using bracket notation

```
 var obj = {};
 var name = ['first'];
 obj[name[0]]='whatever';
```

Last but not a secure way is using:

```
eval('var '+name+' = '+value+';');
```

Eval evaluate the string as a javascript command therefore you can make up your variables with their names made dynamically.

Comment: Using `eval` can be insecure. Ensure that no part of it can be entered by a user.

Comment: anyone can run js on the console so they can run any string as js code so it makes no difference

Comment: If anyone stumbling upon this answer I going to use this on a production website this can create security issues. Your answer is perfectly right, I just wanted to mention [the problem of `eval()`](https://jslinterrors.com/eval-is-evil)

Comment: Yeah I know your concerns but as I mentioned javascript code can be run in your website even if you don't put any evals. The problem with eval is in languages like php, etc.

Comment: I know this is old as hell, but I leave this here for anyone reading in the future. It can be hard to imagine. Of course anyone can run code on their own console. But the problem is letting *someone else* run code on the user's machine when you fetch and eval data from a database. Imagine Twitter using `eval()` to render tweets. You tweet some code and suddenly you're running it on every person that gets your tweet's machine. That's the issue with XSS.

Comment: @Gabriel thanks for the advice, think you can edit the answer to include this? because I agree this is pretty dangerous